# Sabre REST Passenger Details PNR Booking API works in postman but not in my app - 500 Server Error

Tags: angular, sabre

Sabre REST Passenger Detail PNR booking API works fine in postman. But this is not working in my angular 2 app. Also a similar POST call for BargainFinder Max API works fine in our app!
The screenshots from my browser has been attached which describes the payload.
From the screenshot you can see that OPTION call is made with a 500 server error for my post. We have cross checked multiple times to see if everything matches with what we are sending in POSTMAN. 
Please help.

PS: We converted postman request which was working to corresponding code in javascript-xhr through postman code link. We copied this code in a simple html file within script tag. Still the same 500 server issue comes. Only direct postman hit is working! Tried with chrome and firefox browsers.

Thanks

screen shot-1 [sabre 500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t21Qu.png)

screen shot-2 [sample request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OaDJ.png)

Comment: provide some more details what you are trying. no screen shot found.

Comment: The screen shot have been attached your help be appreciated

Comment: you should contact to sabre customer service for this its 500 so they will understand what is happening at backend.

Comment: We interacted with sabre customer service..They couldn't resolve. they suggested us add to stack overflow.

Comment: do you have any working request json?  compare your request json with that json and see the differences.

Comment: Thanks pravin we have done this looking for an alternative

Comment: I wonder if that transaction actually goes to Sabre, I think it doesn't... it makes no sense to work in one and fail on the other.